# How to get hour from current time using dates.getHour

Tags: bixby

I am trying to get the current hour of the time which i try in this approach.

```
var currentTimeHour = dates.ZonedDateTime.now().getHour()
```

It did return value but it is zero while my time is 3pm. And i notice when the time turn to 4pm, the value return become one.

I did tried getMinute and getDay and it seems fine. Did i did anything wrong and is there anyway to get the hour of the current time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dates.ZonedDateTime.now().getHour()` is correct one to use. 
Or you may want to use just `dates.ZonedDateTime.now().time.hour`

```
  var myNow = dates.ZonedDateTime.now()
  console.log('myNow', myNow)
  var myHour = dates.ZonedDateTime.now().getHour()
  console.log('myNow.getHour()', myHour)
```

Let's try the above code in JS file, and can see clearly the structure of now() in debug console. As the following screenshot.
[image]

First confirm the timezone is correct. IDE may change to a different timezone. This is the screenshot if I change IDE to Indiana timezone. 
[image]

To confirm/change IDE timezone, use simulator -> User -> GPS/Clock override feature.
[image]

Comment: I see, so for me, it's the problem on the timezone. Thanks !